Suggestions on easy way to use hardware diagnostic tools
I've been using Ubuntu for a while but I've never really had to get involved with the more complicated side of things, or anything outside of the normal system settings and some basic terminal stuff.
Recently I've had problems with my computer crashing (screen freezes, including mouse, fixed only by a forced restart). I believe that maybe one or multiple computer components maybe on their last legs as they are quite old (specifically, CPU,RAM & motherboard) and I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of some hardware diagnostic tools that I can run in the background and look for any anomalies when my computer inevitably crashes (preferably something someone inexperienced like me can install and interpret without too much trouble) or if there's anything else I could do that would be great to.
For anyone who would like details here's what I know at the moment:

There doesn't seem to be any pattern to when the crash occurs, its happened whilst running high intensity games (Metro Exodus), but has also occurred whilst I was trying to login to my computer, once when I was pairing the Bluetooth and another time whilst watching a YouTube video, (these are not the only times its happened just the ones I recall)

The crash freezes all graphics on the screen, and sometimes but not always disables sound, the keyboard and mouse both become unresponsive, the only thing that I've found so far to fix it is a force restart with the power button.

One other thing of note is that the crashes did not improve after a full reinstall of Ubuntu and are actually now occurring more often.


EDIT: I just checked the logs and I think around time of last crash I got these errors all one after another:
14:31:19 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:31:19 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:31:19 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:31:19 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:31:19 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:31:19 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:31:19 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:31:19 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:31:19 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:31:19 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:31:19 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:31:19 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:31:19 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:31:17 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:31:16 systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dssh-2304.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
14:31:12 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
14:30:54 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
14:30:51 kernel: usb 1-1.3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
14:30:51 kernel: usb 1-1.3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
14:30:51 kernel: usb 1-1.3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
14:30:48 (uetoothd): sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
14:30:48 (uetoothd): sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
14:30:48 (uetoothd): profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialization failed.
14:30:48 kernel: ucsi_ccg 1-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
14:30:48 kernel: ucsi_ccg 1-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
14:30:48 kernel: ucsi_ccg 1-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
14:30:48 kernel: nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
14:30:47 kernel: 
14:30:47 kernel: usb 1-1.3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
14:30:47 kernel: hid-generic 0003:1C4F:0202.0003: unbalanced collection at end of report description
14:30:46 kernel: x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS

If it helps here are my specs:
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-12-01 14:54:48

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. H77M-D3H
Memory:                                      24.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i7-3770 × 8
Graphics:                                    NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER
Disk Capacity:                               2.1 TB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            F6
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-49-generic


This is a Question and Answer support site; where the question should be a clearly defined problem that needs to be solved; with different answers offering a suggestion. Your question is very broad (as I see it) and would be better suited on a Forum (Ubuntu Forums may better suit; see https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/welcome-to-support-and-help/49951). For exploring hardware problems I start with the hardware itself (ie. CAP check using your eyes; even good components fail when fed poor power so PSU check etc) but that's off-topic here. Almost every software crash leaves clues in logs

This question is similar to: Screen suddenly flashes, becomes grainy and shows visual artifacts. "If you ever get repeating audio loops and a frozen screen together when playing an online video, that confirms it." If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
